# Can you accept a NuGet package license via the command line

Tags: nuget

We had NuGet package "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" locked down to version `4.0.4.403061554` (via the allowedVersions attribute) for incompatibility reasons.  We have recently corrected those and now I want to update that package to the latest version (5.2.1).  I removed the allowedVersions attribute and I am able to update the package via Visual Studio Package Manager, but not via the command line.  The command line completes successfully, but it doesn't update the package (note it does for other packages).  There is no indication in the output that there was any kind of problem.  I suspect this is because I have to accept a license agreement via Package Manager and I am not doing that via the command line (this may be incorrect of course).  I have over 30 projects to update and doing them one at a time in Visual Studio is not desirable.

Is my assumption correct about the licensing?

Also, is there a way to update the package via the command line?.

For clarification - we are using Nuget 3.5.0.1996, Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 7 (and, no, I can't upgrade any of those).  I have a .bat file that I run that issues the following commands:
NuGet restore  -NonInteractive
NuGet update  -NonInteractive

This does not cause the aforementioned package to update.  It will update using Visual Studio Package Manager, but that means I have to do each or our projects individually.

Actually, the license request is for another package that "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" needs to update.  It is "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt".  But as far as I can tell, that is the only thing that separates updating this package from any other that does work.

Comment: The PowerShell Package Manager should show you a warning about a license but should still update it. So I suspect there is another problem.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear.  I don't want to do this via Visual Studio.  I have almost 50 projects to update.  I have a .bat file that will walk a tree looking for .sln files and use the NuGet CLI to update them.  However, the identified project does not update during that process.  It will only update using the Package Manager.  Which means I have to do each project individually.  Again, not desirable.

Comment: Probably should update the question with more information and what you have tried. Not sure exactly what is meant by 'update from the command line' - presumably you are using nuget update?